# Is possible to Show Dialog box in Service [android app]?

Tags: java, android, service

I'm a new to android, so I'm trying to develop an application that shows a notification to the user after specific time,  I don't know: Is it possible to use a dialog box inside Service ! or not !...

My Goal is: to ask him a question after specific time, as shown below in my code,

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        // For Notification
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Conformation");
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Expand Report Region?");
        alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Sending a Message to server that the plaintiff wants to
                // expand report region
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also I don't know shall I use Service or BroadcastReceiver ??

any suggestion, thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to use Broadcast receiver and Service both. Register intents in broadcast receiver and from broadcast receiver redirect request to Service.

Its possible to show dialog box from service. only thing you need is an Activity.

In short your application will have one Activity , One Service and one Broadcast receiver. Your broadcast receiver will catch the intent which will redirect to a Service and then your service will invoke activity which shows dialog box.

BroadCast Receiver -- > Service --> Activity

Comment: thanks for you, but I didn't get you well, can you explain more please, will be thankful. =')

Comment: if  i create an activity then call the broadcastRecevier and this calls Service how can I make service call the basic activity+ how can I make the activity show the dialogAlert without pressing any button, !!!!

Comment: Not Your Activity will call BroadcastReciever. BroadcastReceiver will be called by Android. And then from your broadcast receiver  you will invoke Service and Service will invoke your Activity. Read more about how Broadcast reciever works

Answer (score 0):

BroadCast Receiver -- > Service --> Activity  this sequence is good.
For displaying alert dialog without pressing any button call method, showDialog() in Activity's onCreate() method.